# Windows 7 Search Network Path

Tags: search, windows-7, unc, windows-search

Is there any way to index a UNC / Network Path with Windows 7 without making that path "Always Available offline"?

With Windows XP there was Windows Desktop Search that allowed to index a UNC Path but with Windows 7, this option seems to have disappeared.

Since many people use a external NAS storage, there must be some way to index those from Windows 7 to be able to find text in Files like Pdf, Word, etc.

Making the entire NAS "Always Available offline" is of course not a valid solution

Any help is appreciated

Andy

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to add a folder to the index is to simply add the folder to a library. Choose Start→Documents (or Music or whatever), click the Library Locations link in the upper-right corner, and add the folder. The folder you add can be on your PC or on the network. - This will add a network folder to as a non-indexed library.

**Addendum:**
To index a network folder, consider using google desktop with the following registry changes:
[Using Google Desktop Search as a network search server](http://www.geekzone.co.nz/content.asp?contentid=3939)

Comment: this will not actually add the folder to the index. Therefor search will be very slow on these folders especially if they are TB size! With Windows XP there was the UNCFATPATHInstaller that actually allowed you to add a UNC path to the index, but this is not available anymore on Windows 7